# Ordernar Strings en orden alfabetico con Java

Tags: java, poo, bucle-for, substring, concatenación

Estoy realizando un programa en Java que obtiene las substrings de una cadena dada pero tengo duda en como puedo hacer que las substrings obtenidas y concatenadas se ordenen alfabeticamente?.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
public class Substring {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s="dbac";

    System.out.println("Las substrings de la palabra son:");

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){


       for(int j=i+1;j<=s.length();j++){

       String r = s.substring(i, j);
       System.out.println(r);



       }

       }
```

Las substrings obtenidas son:

```
  d db dba dbac b ba bac a ac c
```

Comment: Para ordenarlas necesitas almacenarlas en una variable que contenga a todas como un List o un arreglo. Luego debes ordenar el arreglo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas sencillo es crear y almacenar tus variables en una lista, por ejemplo así
:

```
public class Substring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Esta es la lista creada
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        String s = "dbac";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= s.length(); j++) {
                String r = s.substring(i, j);
                lista.add(r);//Se añaden al la lista
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(lista);//Este es el metodo que ordena la lista.

        System.out.println("Las substrings de la palabra son:");
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(lista.get(i));//Se imprimen
        }
    }
}
```

también puedes utilizar un arreglo y ordenarlo mediante el uso del for anidado, pero necesitarías saber el tamaño del numero de resultados posibles, por eso es más recomendable las listas.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="dbac";
        /* Creamos una lista para cargar las SubString */
        ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Las substrings de la palabra son:");

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j <= s.length(); j++) {
                r.add(s.substring(i, j));
            }
        }
        /* Usamos el metodo sort para ordenarlas */
        Collections.sort(r);
        //Pro ultimo las imprimos y el resultado estará en orden alfabético
        for (String var : r) {
            System.out.println(var);
        }
    }
```